# How to override modifyIndex in consul kv

Tags: hashicorp-vault, consul, hashicorp, consul-kv

I are doing parallel write to primary and secondary consul clusters. When they same value is updated in both the clusters against a key, both of them will have different `modifyIndex`

When I `GET` the same key from both the clusters the `modifyIndex` will be different and our cache which is dependent on modifyIndex is not giving the optimal performance.

How can I make sure both clusters will have same `modifyIndex` ?

Can I write to primary cluster first and get the modifyIndex and then write to secondary by overriding the modifyIndex to the value which I got from Primary cluster? Can this be achieved?